# Prove $(4 + 3 \cdot 3^{1/3} + 2 \cdot 3^{2/3})^{-1}$ is an algebraic integer

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, roots, minimal-polynomials

Let $b = (4 + 3 \cdot 3^{1/3} + 2 \cdot 3^{2/3})^{-1}$, then $1 = b(4 + 3 \cdot 3^{1/3} + 2 \cdot 3^{2/3})$, and $1 - 4b = b(3 \cdot 3^{1/3} + 2 \cdot 3^{2/3})$.

Therefore $1 - 12b + 48b^2 - 64b^3 = (1 - 4b)^3 = b^3(3 \cdot 3^{1/3} + 2 \cdot 3^{2/3})^3$

$= b^3(81  + 18 \cdot 3^{2/3} \cdot 3^{2/3} + 12 \cdot 3^{1/3} \cdot 3^{4/3} + 72) = b^3(153 + 18 \cdot 3 \cdot 3^{1/3} +  18 \cdot 2 \cdot 3^{2/3})$

$= 18b^3(4 +  3 \cdot 3^{1/3} +   2 \cdot 3^{2/3}) + 81b^3 = 18b^3(b^{-1}) + 81b^3= 18b^2 + 81b^3$. Therefore $b$ is a root of $1 - 12b + 48b^2 - 64b^3 - 18b^2 - 81b^3 = - 145b^3 + 30b^2 - 12b + 1$

My problem is $145b^3 - 30b^2 + 12b - 1$ is not monic and is also not reducible, since if it were reducible being of degree $3$ we could factor out a root, which we can't by the rational roots theorem,

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why, according to you, shall the polynomial be a monic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake occurs at this step
$$(3 \cdot 3^{1/3} + 2 \cdot 3^{2/3})^3=(81  + 18 \cdot 3^{2/3} \cdot 3^{2/3} + 12 \cdot 3^{1/3} \cdot 3^{4/3} + 72)$$

Here you have forgotten the binomial coefficients $\binom{3}{1}$ and $\binom{3}{2}$.

Comment: wow can't believe I missed that. I should probably get more sleep.

Answer (score 3):

I think, there is a mistake in your computations.

We obtain:
$$4b-1+3b\sqrt[3]3+2b\sqrt[3]9=0$$ or
$$(4b-1)^3+81b^3+72b^3-3(4b-1)\cdot18b^2=0$$ or $$b^3+6b^2+12b-1=0.$$